# Custom pagination in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pagination

Can anyone suggest whether the below query format is correct?

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM ( SELECT b.*
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by b.TEST_NO) R
             FROM ( select r.* 
                      from ( select TEST_NO , TEST_NO1, TEST_NO2 
                               From test_table
                              where TEST_NO2  = '0000as23') r 
            where 1 = 1 
               and rownum < 10000  ) b
         )
 WHERE R BETWEEN 11 and 200;
```

Here I am trying to achieve custom pagination using Oracle syntax.

Comment: What are your criteria for "correctness"?

Comment: If it returns what you want, it may be correct. If it doesn't, it is certainly not correct.

Comment: This [pagination page](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page) is a pretty good place to start.